# HTTP request in Laravel don't work

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route file:

```
Route::get('/','guzzle@guzzle');
```

And this is my controller class:

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class guzzle extends Controller
{
    public function guzzle(){

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->head('http://www.amazon.com');

    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getContentLength();
```

It gave me the following error message in my browser:

> FatalErrorException in guzzle.php line 17:
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

I don't know how to fix this issue. Who can help me?

Comment: Instead of `use GuzzleHttp\Client;`, use `use \GuzzleHttp\Client;`. What you are currently doing is calling GuzzleHttp as if it is in the same namespace which it is not.

Comment: i tried that one too the error that iam getting looks like this::::::;    cURL error 7: Failed to connect to www.amason.com port 443: Timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: `Failed to connect to www.amason.com` Are you sure it's going to `www.amazon.com` and not `www.amason.com` ?

Comment: Sorry my typo error..... It actually failed to connect to any website. even my school website ::::: i get always this error :::::::cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Sorry my typo error..... It actually failed to connect to any website. even my school website ::::: i get always this error :::::::cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: As the error mentions, this is a certificate problem. Head over to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28858351/6270112) to solve this.

Comment: Tnx i will try that one

Comment: @bytesarelife `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` is perfectly fine. It's `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();` that'd be a problem - it can be just `new Client` because of the `use`.

Comment: @ceejayoz `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`. Clearly namespace prefixing a problem there because it's trying to find the `Client` in the same namespace i.e: `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: @bytesarelife That error is caused by the `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client` line. Not the `use GuzzleHttp\Client` one. Yes, OP has an issue with namespacing. No, "Instead of use GuzzleHttp\Client;, use use \GuzzleHttp\Client;" will not fix it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course, just namespace fix will not resolve the issue. I was just pointing it as one of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get rid of the namespace prefixing with this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have imported the class:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

You **should not** type the full class namespace while instantiating it:

wrong: `new GuzzleHttp\Client();`

right: `new Client();`